# R cannot allocate vector. Where is the object?

Tags: programming

I misjudged how much memory would be required and my computer ran out of memory when R was 76% done with an lapply function. Is there a way to recover and saveRDS the object or do I have to start over from the beginning?

Comment: Since you are posting to Open Data SE, I am going to give you the benefit of the doubt and deduce that you are talking about working with an open data source. Could you tell us more about the data you're working with?

Comment: I only posted here because when I posted this in the crossvalidated se a mod locked it and said I should post it here and I'm on my last warning. It was just a simple question nothing worth getting banned over. I assume the answer is no, but google did not provide any clear answers.